# Moving an AD user from an OU to another OU

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to move active directory user from one organization unit to another using C#.

I have referred below links

1. http://forums.asp.net/t/932664.aspx?Moving+an+AD+user+from+an+OU+to+another+OU
2. http://www.nullskull.com/q/10279930/to-move-a-user-from-one-ou-to-another-ou.aspx

and tried below code, but it throws error

```
DirectoryEntry eLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Test User,OU=Users,OU=Development,DC=domain,DC=com");
DirectoryEntry nLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,OU=QC,DC=domain,DC=com");
eLocation.MoveTo(nLocation);
```

Above code throws below error

```
A referral was returned from the server.
Error code: -2147016661
Extended Error Message 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-0310082F, data 0, 1 access points
ref 1: 'domain.com'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have passed user credentials as below and it worked like a charm.

```
DirectoryEntry eLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Test User,OU=Users,OU=Development,DC=domain,DC=com", "domain\admin", "password");
DirectoryEntry nLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,OU=QC,DC=domain,DC=com", "domain\admin", "password");
eLocation.MoveTo(nLocation);
nLocation.Close();
eLocation.Close();
```

Comment: I used the same code that you provided but I get the following error: "A referral was returned from the server"

Answer (score 0):

If you use other server in other domain that you need to set name of target server where you are moving the object:

```
DirectoryEntry theObjectToMove = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://otherdomain.com/CN=TestUser,CN=Users,DC=otherdomain,DC=com");
DirectoryEntry theNewParent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://otherdomain.com/OU=Something,DC=otherdomain,DC=com");
theObjectToMove.MoveTo(theNewParent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new [AccountManagement Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN) you can achieve the same with:

```
public void MoveUser(UserPrincipal user) {
    var userEntry = (DirectoryEntry) user.GetUnderlyingObject();
    var newOU = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,OU=QC,DC=domain,DC=com", "domain\admin", "password");
    userEntry.MoveTo(newOU);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any credentials to pass
I did the following

```
DirectoryEntry oDE= new DirectoryEntry(LDAP://" + "CN="xxx OU=xxxx,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx");
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+ "OU=xxxx,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx");
oDE.MoveTo(de);
```